# Python Oozie Shell Action Failing

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have an Oozie workflow that contains a shell action that invokes a Python script that is failing with the following error.

```
Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

The Python script (hello.py) is simple.

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

Here is my Oozie workflow.

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="hello">
<start to="shell-check-hour"/>

<action name="shell-check-hour">
<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
<value>${queueName}</value>
</property>
</configuration>
<exec>hello.py</exec>
<file>hdfs://localhost:8020/user/test/hello.py</file>
<capture-output/>
</shell>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="fail"/>
</action>
<kill name="fail">
<message>Workflow failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Can someone see anything wrong with what I am doing? If I replace the Python script with a shell script, the shell script executes fine (both files are in the same directory). This leads me to believe that the problem is that for whatever reason, Python isn't being recognised by Oozie.

Comment: Try to find more specific information about the failure in the various logs (Oozie log, and also the log of the map task that performs the shell action). Also, try to replace `<exec>hello.py</exec>` with `<exec>python</exec><argument>hello.py</argument>`.

Comment: Thank you Eli Acherkan .. Post this as answer it worked .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [Hash-Bang](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Shebang_(Unix)) to your script

For example, my script started with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```